# segmentation fault (exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)) when using multiprocessing.shared_memory.ShareMemory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I'm trying to load `List[np.ndarray]` into `shared_memory` such that other processes can directly access this `shared_memory` and recover the original `List[np.ndarray]` without copying `List[np.ndarray]` into every process. The detailed motivation is related to my previous question: [share read-only generic complex python object with int, list of numpy array, tuple, etc. as instance field between multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238558/share-read-only-generic-complex-python-object-with-int-list-of-numpy-array-tup?noredirect=1#comment124166167_70238558)

I wrote the following code(**python version: 3.8.12, Numpy:1.20.3,  MacOS**):

`encode_nd_arr_list()`: given `List[np.ndarray]`, I can get `List of share_memory name`.
`decode_nd_arr_list()`: given `List of share_memory name`, I can recover original `List[np.ndarray]`.

```
from typing import List, Tuple
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager


def encode_nd_arr_list(
        smm: SharedMemoryManager,
        nd_arr_list: List[np.ndarray]
):

    shm_name_list = []
    shape, dtype = nd_arr_list[0].shape, nd_arr_list[0].dtype
    print(shape)
    print(dtype)
    for nd_arr in nd_arr_list:
        shm = smm.SharedMemory(size=nd_arr.nbytes)
        shm_arr = np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
        np.copyto(shm_arr, nd_arr)
        shm_name_list.append(shm.name)
    return shm_name_list, shape, dtype


def decode_nd_arr_list(
        shm_name_list: List[str],
        shape: Tuple[int],
        dtype: np.dtype
):

    nd_array_list = []
    for shm_name in shm_name_list:
        print("----------")
        shm = SharedMemory(shm_name)
        nd_arr = np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
        print("nd_arr:", nd_arr)
        nd_array_list.append(nd_arr)
        print("nd_array_list:", nd_array_list)
    return nd_array_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
    nd_arr_list = [arr, arr + 1, arr + 2]
    print(nd_arr_list)
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        shm_name_list, shape, dtype = encode_nd_arr_list(smm, nd_arr_list)
        print(shm_name_list)
        print(shape)
        print(dtype)
        res = decode_nd_arr_list(shm_name_list, shape, dtype)
        print("------------")
        print(res)
```

However, when I run it in `PyCharm`, the console shows `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`. When I run it in the terminal, it shows `segmentation fault`, without any error information.

My Question:

1. What's this fault meaning in my case?
2. How can I make my code work? Thanks.

Comment: also related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/63713241/10969942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffers that are used in each iteration of the loop in the `decode_nd_arr_list` method get closed after the corresponding `SharedMemory` object goes out of scope and that causes the segfault. You are essentially trying to access a memory that is no longer valid.

In order to fix it, you can create a custom object that wraps around the ndarray and also stores the `SharedMemory` to prevent it from going out of scope.

**Example:**

```py
from typing import List, Tuple
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager


class SHMArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, shm=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.shm = shm
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.shm = getattr(obj, 'shm', None)

def encode_nd_arr_list(
        smm: SharedMemoryManager,
        nd_arr_list: List[np.ndarray]
):

    shm_name_list = []
    shape, dtype = nd_arr_list[0].shape, nd_arr_list[0].dtype
    print(shape)
    print(dtype)
    for nd_arr in nd_arr_list:
        shm = smm.SharedMemory(size=nd_arr.nbytes)
        shm_arr = np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
        np.copyto(shm_arr, nd_arr)
        shm_name_list.append(shm.name)
    return shm_name_list, shape, dtype


def decode_nd_arr_list(
        shm_name_list: List[str],
        shape: Tuple[int],
        dtype: np.dtype
):

    nd_array_list = []
    for shm_name in shm_name_list:
        print("----------")
        shm = SharedMemory(shm_name)
        nd_arr = SHMArray(np.ndarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf), shm)
        print("nd_arr:", nd_arr)
        nd_array_list.append(nd_arr)
        print("nd_array_list:", nd_array_list)
    return nd_array_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
    nd_arr_list = [arr, arr + 1, arr + 2]
    print(nd_arr_list)
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        shm_name_list, shape, dtype = encode_nd_arr_list(smm, nd_arr_list)
        print(shm_name_list)
        print(shape)
        print(dtype)
        res = decode_nd_arr_list(shm_name_list, shape, dtype)
        print("------------")
        print(res)
```

Reference: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18294#issuecomment-771329575